# Why is type_traits implemented using structs

Tags: c++, type-traits

Most of type traits are made using struct and template partial(or full) specialization. For example `std::is_same` is implemented as

```
template<typename>
struct is_same : false_type {};
template<typename T>
struct is_same<T, T> : true_type {}; // partial specialization
```

The usage would be

```
bool are_equal = std::is_same<T, U>::value;
```

or

```
.. = std::is_same_v<T, U>;
```

which are both a bit ugly.
At first I thought it was the only solution then I found out that variables can also be partially specialized(while functions can not).
Type transformation traits cannot (obviusly) be variables but for "information" traits why this wouldn't be better than a struct?

```
template<typename>
inline constexpr bool is_same = false;
template<typename T>
inline constexpr bool is_same<T, T> = true;
```

And then

```
bool are_equal = std::is_same<T, U>;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is merely historical. Most type traits were added to the library first, in C++11. Variable templates were added later in C++14, and that point changing the implementation was unfeasible, since that is too backwards incompatible. Variables with a `_v` suffix were therefore added, and that became the convention.

New traits are added the same way because it's important to have consistency in any library, let alone the standard library.

Comment: `inline` variables were also a C++17 feature, which is why the `_v` templates didn't appear until then too.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, you want a type, not just an underlying `bool` value. Simple example is provided by the tag dispatch technique:

```
void foo(std::true_type)  { ... }
void foo(std::false_type) { ... }

foo(std::is_same<T, S>{});
```

If `std::is_same` were just a `bool` variable template, this code would not be that elegant.

Comment: I'm unsure as to why that code is particularly elegant. What's going on in those functions that it can't be done as a conditional within the function? What's the point of doing tag dispatch around a *boolean* value? If it's `constexpr` stuff, then you could easily pass the bool as a non-type template parameter and use `if constexpr`.

Comment: @NicolBolas, if these two `foo`s were doing different things, I'd prefer to have them as two separate functions rather than having two branches for `if constexpr` inside a single one.

Comment: If they're truly doing such distinct things, shouldn't they have distinct names? Why would you be trying to invoke one or the other based on a difference in parameters? That is, from the perspective of the reader of `foo(is_same<T, S>{})`, I would be expecting that a `foo` is being performed, whatever that means. Not possibly a `foo` and possible a `non-foo`.

Comment: @NicolBolas, they can do the same thing differently, like `std::distance` does the same thing for random access and forward iterators in completely different ways.

Comment: It's a matter of interface vs. implementation. You would *implement* `distance` in different ways based on properties of the iterator type it uses. But the *interface* for `distance` should not expose that detail to the user. Tagged dispatch as part of the primary interface for the type is exposing an implementation detail to the interface.

Comment: @NicolBolas, I totally agree. *Inside* standard library implementations code of that type is ubiquitous. And I doubt that it would become more elegant it if were rewritten using `if constexpr` branches instead of tag dispatch.

Answer (score 0):

Note that type and non-type parameters are not interchangeable. You cannot write an unary template that accepts both. If you were to build a full-fledged compile-time computational algebra you'd need to pick one parameter type and make all your templates accept only that.